# How to deploy Java Swing Application

Tags: java, mysql, swing, executable-jar, setup-deployment

I have developed a Swing Application. For Back end I have used MySQL and I have developed this application using JDK 1.8 version.
I want to create .exe file of my Java project along with MySQL installer and JDK installer

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can export a .jar file (every IDE has one option to do this), what you make your project open just as one .exe if the pc has a JRE installed.

For the Integrated installer, you will have to use a program to integrate the installer of mysql, JDK/JRE, and your .jar file.

I do not know such program but I'm sure that it exists. Surely someone you recommend one to you.